# how to make timer with for-loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, timer

how to start and stop timer within for loop.
this timer do something

```
for i as integer =0 to 100
timer1.start
'process something
timer1.stop
next i

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
'do something
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? What's the general purpose of this ? Because I have a feeling you don't fully understand how Timers work (not a critic).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the timer altogether.

```
for i as integer =0 to 100
DoSomething()
next i

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    DoSomething()
End Sub

Sub DoSomething()
    ' do something
End Sub
```